# Positioning divs left and right within anohter div

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

I am quite new to css and html, and I am having trouble floating divs within a another div,
I've done quite a bit of research online but have not been able to come up with a solution.

**these are the sites I have read and where of no use:**

barelyfitz /screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

stackoverflow /questions/580195/css-layout-2-column-fixed-fluid

mirificampress /show.php?id=106

[How to get Floating DIVs inside fixed-width DIV to continue horizontally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015809/how-to-get-floating-divs-inside-fixed-width-div-to-continue-horizontally)

My code can be found on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qf3BB/)

Comment: Make sure you're closing your tags properly. Your divs don't have the correct closing tags, and hence they're not wrapping your content like I believe you expect them to.

Comment: I removed floats to try something I found at http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will help.
CSS:

```
#left, #right {
 width: 100px; //change this to whatever required
 float: left;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left">
       <p class="t0">lorum itsum left</p>
    <div>
    <div id="right">
       <p class="t0">lorum itsum right</p>
    <div>
<div>
```

Comment: KinaKuta was correct, *sigh* the correct and simple way can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/CCAtj/

Comment: I just found Stackoverflow, you guys are wonderful, now to get a editor instead of doing every thing with notepad... Good historical reference though for other noobs. Special thanks to KinaKuta and xFortyFourx

Answer (score 1):

Since you are a beginner. I will make it straight forward. Below is extraction of your code. I used internal style sheet. Your example you are using external style sheet.
        Using float attribute you can set it to left and right. Here is used float:left to alight one div to left and float:right to alight other one to the right.
        Each opened  tag has to be closed  tag.

```
    <head>
    </head> 
    <!--Internal style sheet-->
    <style>
    .left{
    float:left;
    }
    .right{
    float:right;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="wrapper" >
        <div class="left">
            <p class="t0">lorum itsum left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <p class="t0">lorum itsum right</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Additional note: If you want to adjust the size of left and right div then use width in style sheet. Refer the updated style sheet below. I made left div width to 80% of the screen width and right width to 20%.(total should be 100%). Adjust accordingly.Background color used to set the background color of the div.

```
.left{
float:left;
background-color:powderblue;
width:80%;
}
.right{
float:right;
width:20%;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ev474/

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="left">
            Left Content
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            Right Content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

div {
    height: 50px;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 200px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
#inner {
    width: 400px;
}
#left {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #f00;
}
#right {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #0f0;
}​
```