# css - why text-decoration doesn't work under a:hover?

Tags: css

I have the following style rules:

```
.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li a,
.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li a:visited {
  color: #00ff00;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li a span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

Q1> I don't know why the `a:hover` in above code doesn't work. In other words, when the cursor is on top of the navigation item, the underline doesn't show up.

However, I do see the changes of the color when I hover the cursor over the navigation items.

Q2> I am using DW CS4 + Firebug. Is there a way that I can detect which rule suppresses `a:hover` so that I can figure out similar issues in the future?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the text-decoration to show up by applying it to the nested span like so:

```
.twoColFixRt #nav-primary .nav li a:hover span {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color:#FF0000;
}
```

If you're interested as to the reason it's not currently working for you, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371307/displayblock-inside-displayinline) about inline boxes (your `<a>`) containing block boxes (your `<span>`).

As to detecting which rules are being applied to an element, I use the [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) addon for Firefox.  It's **CSS > View Style Information** (CTRL + SHIFT + Y) is especially handy for this.

Comment: Wow. Apparently this is only necessary in Firefox (underline shows up in the original code w Chrome and IE (8) http://jsfiddle.net/vUkZ6/ )

Comment: Hello Pat,

Your solution works very well for me.

Also I installed web developer, just never know how to use it. I use the CSS->View Style Information, however, I didn't where I can find that suppressed rule information.

May you give me a little hint?
Thank you

Comment: @q0987 glad to hear.  The web developer doesn't specifically list suppressed rules.  When you're in `View Style Information`, click on any element and you'll get a list of all styles being applied.  Then you can look over the list and see if anything is being overwritten unintentionally.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the text-decoration property in the inline css of your element. 
If that works, find out what messes up your external css.

Answer (score 0):

The **display** of **before** content must be **block**, it's work fine like this:

```
.category li a {
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.8rem;
}

.category li a::before {
    content: "\2022";
    color: var(--primaryColor);
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 0.4rem;
    float: right;
}

.category li a:hover::before {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```