# How are block children of inline elements defined to be rendered in CSS?

Tags: html, css, browser

I've read the CSS 2.1 [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/) (and later ones) several times, but can't find the specification on how an element with `"display:block;"` with a parent element that has `"display:inline;"` should be rendered.

I've seen several web pages that have such elements, so wondering how browsers handle this.

Comment: It is  like `<div>` wrapped inside a `<span>`.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371307/displayblock-inside-displayinline

Comment: It ain't [pretty](http://jsfiddle.net/6os9nz8y/2/), but is [well defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level).

Comment: @wero or Marc, if either of you posts an answer, I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: No need - it's a duplicate question. (I don't understand why wero didn't cast a close vote.)