# Show two list item side by side in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am using React 15 to generate two lists from two separate components.
I want the list to be aligned side by side. Something like this

[image]

But what I'm getting is

[image]

Now the problem is

- These are two separate components and I can't merge them in a single one
- In React 15 there should be always one parent wrapper element hence I can't wrap both lists in a single ul.
- There are going to be two `ul` elements which are block elements hence the second `ul` will start from the next line.

Is there any React or CSS solution for it?

Any help will be appreciated.
[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/v3klvz0n9l)

```js
let List1 = function() {
  return (
    <ul className="list1">
      <li>List1</li>
      <li>List2</li>
      <li>List3</li>
      <li>List4</li>
      <li>List5</li>
    </ul>
  );
};

let List2 = function() {
  return (
    <ul className="list2">
      <li>List6</li>
      <li>List7</li>
      <li>List8</li>
      <li>List9</li>
      <li>List10</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List1 />
        <List2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

 <div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but you can change the ULs to `display: inline`.

```js
let List1 = function() {
  return (
    <ul className="list1">
      <li>List1</li>
      <li>List2</li>
      <li>List3</li>
      <li>List4</li>
      <li>List5</li>
    </ul>
  );
};

let List2 = function() {
  return (
    <ul className="list2">
      <li>List6</li>
      <li>List7</li>
      <li>List8</li>
      <li>List9</li>
      <li>List10</li>
    </ul>
  );
};
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <List1 />
        <List2 />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
ul {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>

 <div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make it something like the added screenshot?

Comment: Thanks, Ori Drori. I was just wondering if `inline-block` elements inside `inline` element valid or not?

Comment: I feel it's a hack, but this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415625/5157454) shows that the spec actually refer to this situation. In addition, it actually works in chrome/firefox/edge. Your call.