# Is it possible in CSS to outline/color an element with `display:block` children?

Tags: html, css

I have the following DOM layout:

```html
<div style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);outline:1px solid red;display:inline">
  This should be marked
  <div>i want this too</div>
  and this too
</div>
```

I want to style the outer `div` that is outlines or colors the background of its whole area, the inner `div` included, like in the Chrome devtools if you select a part of the DOM:

[image: desired result]

My restriction is that I cannot change the styles inside the `span`, it has always different children (I can write any CSS to the outer `span` though, that doesn't change the position/dimensions). Basically I want to replicate the Chrome devtools DOM highlighter.

How to do this?

Comment: your html is invalid - you can't put a div inside a span, but you should be able to achieve what you want making the span inline-block

Comment: @AniketPandey — No, you can't. The HTML specification is quite clear. [Only *phrasing content* is permitted inside a span](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element).

Comment: @Pete sorry, I forgot to mention I cannot have there stuff that changes the dimensions of the `span`. I'm basically trying to replicate the Chrome devtools selector -- something that highlights the dimensions of a component without changing its or its childrens position/dimensions

Comment: well the only way to highlight full width would be to make the span display block but if you can't do that then you really can't do what you are wanting

Comment: ill also edit my code to be a valid HTML to not sidetrack the convo

Comment: Ive edited my HTML to be valid

Comment: @sydd The reason for the seen styling is answered in that question [display:block inside display:inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371307)  by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415625/1960455) `When an inline box contains a block box, the inline box [...] [is] broken around the block. The [in]line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous boxes, and the block box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes.` So the inner `div` will never get the styling of the "surrounding" `inline` element.

Answer (score 2):

## Why it is happening

The `<span>` tag has `display: inline` property enabled by default. It says the browser to embed text content and child tags **with display: inline** to text. For example:

```css
.styled {
  border: 5px dashed deeppink;
  background: #00cccc;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <span class="styled">ips<b>um</b></span> dolor sit amet...</p>
<!-- <b> has display: inline by default -->
<p>Lorem <span class="styled">ips<div style="font-weight: bold; ">um</div></span> dolor sit amet...</p>
<!-- <div> has display: block by default, so it has not been styled -->
```

## Solution

You can replace this tag by `<div>` or set `display: block;` property to it, so your code will look like:

```html
<span style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
             outline: 1px solid red;
             display: block;">
  works1
  <div style="display: block;">I want this too</div>
  works2
</span>
```

## Solution 2

As said in comments to a question, it's unwelcome to put `<div>` into a `<span>`, so you can try this:

```html
<div style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
             outline: 1px solid red;">
  works1
  <div>I want this too</div>
  works2
</div>
```

And remember that  have `display: block;` enabled by default, so you do not need to enable it (fixed in solution 2)

Answer (score 1):

It works exactly the way you want:

```
<span style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);outline:1px solid red; display: block;">
  works1
  <div style="display:block">I want this too</div>
  works2
</span>
```

Although simply changing the display property of your span will do the trick but I think it is something that you should not do. span can be inside of a div but a div should not be inside of a span.