# Why can't I make these things show on the same line?

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="demo" style="display: inline;">

<div style="color:#DD4814; font-weight:bold; font-size:25px;">Buscá tu colegio:</div>

<img src="Imagenes/info.png" title="Escribí el nombre <u>completo</u>. Si es un colegio no escribás 'colegio' o 'escuela' a menos que sea 'Escuela Normal', 'Escuela 1' o similar."/>
</div>
```

I tried display:inline I thought that was the way to do it. I couldn't anyway I'm sure it's easy. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only put inline on the first div. The other is a block element by default, which ensures that it will have a linebreak before and after it.

Oh, I just noticed that the second div is nested in the first. `display: inline` is not inherited. If you want the things inside the outer div to be inline, you'll need to make them inline.

Comment: nice one Mud. @Liso 22: It's also worth noting that it's generally considered bad practice to nest a block object inside an inline object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another-b

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `display: inline` on each individual element you want to appear on the same line, not the outer/containing element

Also, consider using a `span` for your text. You may also want to look into `float` for the image.