# How to wrap a table in a link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, html-table, href

What elements allow link?

I want to **wrap** a link around a `table`,

```
<a href="123.php" class="grap" >
    <table border="1" style="width:600px; height:600px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border:1px solid red"><img src="thumb-pic-1.jpg" alt="123"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</a>
```

But it is not a correct html as in http://validator.w3.org/

I can put the link in a *form* like this,

```
<form action="123.php" class="grap" >
    <table border="1" style="width:600px; height:600px;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="border:1px solid red"><img src="thumb-pic-1.jpg" alt="123"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

But the `link` or the `table` is not meant to be a form form submission...

I wonder if there are anyway to wrap a table in a link?

**EDIT:**

Sorry forgot the mention that I need to grab the link url like this,

```
$('.grap').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('action'));
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: What about `<table onclick="window.location.href='123.php'">...</table>`? Note that such behavior is uncommon to the user.

Comment: It ought be. You don't always need to be valid when doing things in HTML, but it's highly suggested for various reasons.

Comment: I think a better question is what on earth is that doing as a table when it looks like it can be tackled with flow elements, which *would* allow wrapping in an anchor.

Comment: Uggh, adding a navigation clickhandler to a table is a usability nightmare. Why not just wrap the image inside the table cell in a link?

Comment: @steveax: That would be too easy.... Just kidding. I guess the OP is using a `<table>` to center the image vertically and horizontally. @steveax: I agree. If you can't copy or click the content of a table it is not a table but a static image, so OP could replace the table by an image and avoid all this unnecessary work. However, the additional "grab the URL like this" information baffles me, time to get some sleep, hope I don't dream of usability nightmares.

Answer (score 1):

`<a>` is an Inline-Element and `<table>` is a block element. Block elements are not allowed in inline elements in xhtml. But what about a click listener on the table, or an div around the table? The effect should be the same.

This might be also interesting for you:
[Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another)

Answer (score 1):

Browsers let you wrap a table inside a link. The practical problems with it relate to rendering (browsers may or may not underline the text content and draw borders around images inside a link), not with basic functionality. It’s not valid as per HTML 4.01 for example, but so what?

In your example, the table contains just one cell that contains just one image. You could instead use just an `img` element and style it suitably. In a more complicated case, a table might be useful. Then you should probably set `color` and `text-decoration` for it in CSS and `border` for any `img` contained in it, so that you get the rendering you prefer and not the varying browser default rendering for a situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not wrap a block level element (such as a table) in an inline element (such as an anchor). You could, however, use `display: block;` to make the anchor block level.

You could also use Javascript event handlers to link the table. For instance, you could have this snippet of code in your head tag that assigns an onclick event to the table.

Where, `idOfYourSpecifiedTable` is the id attribute of your table (ie `<table id='idOfYourSpecifiedTable'>`),

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('idOfYourSpecifiedTable').onclick = function() {window.location.href='123.php'};
</script>
```

or in jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#idOfYourSpecifiedTable').click(function() {window.location.href='123.php';});
    });
</script>
```

Furthermore, you could even use `#idOfYourSpecifiedTable {cursor: pointer;}` to make the cursor a pointer (hand) when a client hovers over it.

However, this method has its weaknesses. Notably, a search engine robot will likely not detect your table as linked to another page of your site.

Comment: thanks for answer. how can I do your javacript in jquery? Please see my edit above. thanks.

Comment: I added how to do the same Javascript functionality in jQuery. I wasn't sure what you specifically meant by grab the link URL. Assuming `$('.grap').attr('action')` is your link URL, just replace `'123.php'` (even the single quotes too because that's a string) in my jQuery code above with `$('.grap').attr('action')`.

Comment: it seems that html5 allow us to wrap a block level element in an inline element - http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links so it must be safe to wrap a `table` in a `a` tag, right?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps so based on that article. I still don't feel comfortable wrapping an anchor tag around a block level element. First off, it makes me feel old :P Secondly, it doesn't semantically make sense. How could an inline element (which is literally supposed to be in a line of text) wrap a block element (which is supposed to be an area of the page)?

Comment: Wrapping a table in an `a` element is [perfectly valid in HTML5](http://validator.nu/) but surely you could accomplish the same visual appearance with more straightforward markup. Why not just wrap the `a` around the image, and give it `display: block` and the other styles you have assigned to the table and td?