# HTML table in <a> tag

Tags: html, href

Is it possible to somehow place a whole HTML table in a href link?

Something like: (does not work in IE)

```
    <td class="order_confirm">
        <a href="ssss">
            <div>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td><img src="design/img/icon_ok.png" width="22" height="22" alt="objednat" /></td>
                    <td width="0" class="order_confirm_order">OBJEDNAT</td>
                    <td width="100%" class="order_confirm_order_desc">Záväzne si objednávam uvedený tovar a súhlasím s platobnými,<br />
                      dodacími a obchodnými podmienkami prevádzkovateľa.</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </a>
    </td>
```

I am aware of the fact that this is not the best practice, however, I don't really see a workaround for this using a non-table layout... So a solution with a non-table layout would also be acceptable for me.

Comment: "Place a whole HTML table in a href link"???????? Let's start by telling us what you want to do.

Comment: You have a `td` with width of 100% while you have other `td`s in that row.

Comment: it's work in progress @PeeHaa, don't focus on that :)

Comment: @PeeHaa - get the whole table in a link to use as a button... if possible... as stated in the question - I know it's not the best practice, but maybe there's some kind of workaround for that... if not, I will have to do it using divs...

Comment: What you want to do is perfectly possible without using tables.

Comment: well, how - if div's are disqualified too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap a table in a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754881/how-to-wrap-a-table-in-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your whole table as a link you can simulate it css and javascript.

This example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
<style>
    #big-link {
       cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $("#big-link").click(function() {
        window.location.href = "ssss";
    });
});
</script>
<div id="big-link">
    <table>
         ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, nice option, didn't think of this one... +1 - thanx

Comment: maybe you should edit the answer so that it is clear that this is jQuery - not JS alone... (i know that, but someone else might not...)

Comment: @MichalPlško: That's the same solution that user1150525 proposed, that you said that you *didn't* want to use...

Comment: @Guffa - not really, he proposed an inline java script, this is jQuery... I can separate this into an external file which is a big advantage for me... inline JS can't be separated to an external file, that was my reason why I didn't wanted to use it...

Comment: @MichalPlško: Yes, really. It's the exact same principle, using jQuery is just an implementation detail.

Comment: I made an edit to your answer not as a moderator, but as a long time Stack Overflow user. Many people just cut and paste examples given in an accepted answer, then wonder why they don't work. Yes, some people don't know what jQuery is, and you need to account for that just like you need to account for IE6 users not knowing any better, wherever possible. In this case, such accounting is possible, so I added it :) Remember, the OP is not the only one you're teaching.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't correct to place div's or table's in a. (See selfhtml for more information).

What you can do is something like this:

```
<div onclick="document.location.href = 'new location';">....</div>
```

Comment: +1 for this, however, I am aware of it, I don't want to use it, I hope there's an alternetive...

Comment: +1 For proposing the method that was later repeated and accepted in another answer...

Answer (score 2):

In HTML 5 you can put block elements inside an inline element, so there it would work.

For any browser that doesn't support HTML 5, or if you don't have an HTML 5 doctype in the page, the markup will break, and the `div` and the `table` will end up outside the link.

Comment: yeah, well, doctype is XHTML 1.0 Transitional by now, but it's work in progress, so I might change to HTML5. Will there be any other issues switching the doctype? Never worked with HTML5 yet...

Comment: @MichalPlško: Well, the greatest issue would be with the browsers that doesn't support HTML 5.

Comment: would they kinda "roll-back" to HTML 4.1 or what?

Comment: @MichalPlško: Yes, browsers that doesn't recognise doctypes will fall back to what version it thinks that it might be. Naturally they can't "fall forward" to a version that didn't exist when the browser was released.

Answer (score 0):

Using [html4](/questions/tagged/html4) event attributes you can make the [table](/questions/tagged/table) itself an [anchor-tag](/questions/tagged/anchor-tag).

```
<table
    style="cursor:pointer" 
    onMouseover="window.status='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'" 
    onMouseout="window.status=''" 
    onMouseup="window.location='http://www.stackoverflow.com/'" 
    width="500" height="500">
```