# block element in inline element

Tags: css

I have been attempting to dissect some of the css on the behance.net site. I've looked through it in the chrome inspector pretty thoroughly, but some things I just don't understand.

On the top navigation bar, there is text that says "Discover", "Galleries", "Jobs". I notice that "Discover" is a div inside of an anchor tag. I was under the impression that block level elements could not inhabit inline level elements. But this is a pretty professional looking site, and they're doing it. Does it not break in some browsers?

```
<a    class="nav-link" href="/"><div class="nav-text nav-sprite nav-sprite-discover">Discover</div></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: W3C doesn't seem to be a fan of it http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=behance.net+&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/1085285

Comment: See full discussion of this issue [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the HTML5 documentation, [`<a>`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-a-element.html#the-a-element) elements have a [`transparent` content model](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/content-models.html#transparent), which means they're allowed to contain block level elements.

<sub>In HTML4 and below, `<a>` elements were inline elements, which could not contain block content.</sub>

Comment: @AshishGupta, if you read the link you'll note that it is a reference to the *HTML5* documentation. That previous answer, while correct, is out of date.

Comment: @BoltClock . OP never mentioned HTML5

Comment: @AshishGupta, OP never mentioned HTML4, which means that the latest relevant version is assumed, which is at this point HTML5.

Comment: Is it practicable to give the HTML 4 document to some browsers and 5 to others? Is that what's being done here?

Comment: @thomas, Browsers do their best to render invalid markup. Because of this, the newer HTML5 spec includes some changes and details as to how browsers can *consistently* render invalid markup. Most browsers will allow you to place block elements in inline containers and render them relatively consistently, whether or not the markup is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If Behance were using a HTML5 doctype, this would be valid (as zzzzBov says, a elements have a transparent content model in the current draft of the HTML5 spec, meaning they can contain block-level elements).

However, as they're using an XHTML doctype, their usage in this context is invalid. It won't break on (most) browsers, but it's not strictly correct and I wouldn't emulate it.