# Is it illegal to set the parent of block element to inline display?

Tags: html, css, w3c, w3c-validation

Is it valid CSS to have a block element inside of an inline element?

For example:

```
<a href="#">
    <span></span>
</a>
```

Is `span { display: block; }` illegal while  the `<a>` is inline?

Comment: @d-_-b thank you for editing but you change the meaning of the querstion Iam asking about if is it illegal with css

Comment: @d-_-b : a is default inline :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS rules do not, in any way, influence the validity of markup.

The rules for how to handle `display: block` elements inside `display: inline` elements can be found in [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-boxes).

> When an inline box contains an in-flow block-level box, the inline box (and its inline ancestors within the same line box) are broken around the block-level box (and any block-level siblings that are consecutive or separated only by collapsible whitespace and/or out-of-flow elements), splitting the inline box into two boxes (even if either side is empty), one on each side of the block-level box(es). The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of those anonymous boxes. When such an inline box is affected by relative positioning, any resulting translation also affects the block-level box contained in the inline box.

Comment: So do you mean every thing is right !!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a visual approach in addition to Quentin's answer.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WC9ru/)**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
}

div { 
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px; margin: 12px; 
    background-color: #ccc; 
    width: 70% 
}

.test1 { 
    display: inline; 
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white; 
}

.test2 { 
    display: block; 
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white; 
}

.test3 {
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 25px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: white;
}
```