# Positioning two tables in HTML

Tags: css, html

I'd like to add two tables in my web application:

```
<span><table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table></span>
<span><table><tr><td>C</td><td>B</td></tr></table></span>
```

I'd like that these two tables are positioning at the same row ie. horizontally,

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are you placing a block level element (`table`) inside an inline element (`span`). Or even, why are you placing a table in a span? Just curious

Comment: did you have another version how to place two table horizontally?

Comment: Well, you could just use CSS to change the `display` type of the tables or use `float`, there's absolutely no use to place the tables inside a `span`. (More discussion on block elements inside inline elements here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
<span class="table"><table><tr><td>A</td><td>B</td></tr></table></span>
<span class="table"><table><tr><td>C</td><td>B</td></tr></table></span>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.table{     
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
span{display: inline-table;}
```

or you could also do `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;`

and give width to your table.

see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BkSDY/)

Answer (score 1):

```
span{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/n4J2h/)