# Html anchor weird behaviour

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
```

And the following styles:

```
li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px 7px;
}
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I do it for my navigation bar. This style nicely position my links in the following order:

**Home    About Us    Services ...**

They are all inline because of the li html tag which was styled to be inline element. Now if I change achor syle ot be like this:

```
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
```

I made anchors to be block elements. Suddenly my links will look like this:

**Home**

**About Us**

**Services**

**...**

They become separated by line brakes. But each anchor was contained in li element, which was made inline. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: This problem is thoroughly discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default width of display block is 100%.

```
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

You can specify a smaller one and I assume you want it to float left.

Answer (score 0):

You added  `display: block;` which is creating problem

try this

```
display: inline; OR

display: inline- block;
```

Look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G56dV/).

Comment: I know that I added display block. But in each li element there is only one one anchor and li elements are inline so everything suppose to stay on one line

Comment: Rustam - the li element must be at least as wide as the a element it contains. And your a elements are as wide as the page.