# Why does an <A> overflow parent <DIV> when padding is set

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML vertical menu, with such a structure:

```
<div id="menu">
   <div class="item">
      <a href="...">...</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've set the `.item` div to be rendered as text elements, so they're ordered next to each other:

```
#menu div.item {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline;
}
```

This kinda works:

[image: menu screenshot]
However, I want to apply a `:hover` effect on each link, such as vertical black borders will come from sides and connect with the bottom dashed border:

[image: menu as I want it to look like]

So I did the following:

```
#menu div.item a{

  padding: 5px;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: dashed;
}
#menu div.item a:hover{
  border-color: black;
  background: #B3D2FF;
}
```

But the link seems to be bigger than it's parent element. I didn't think this was possible:

[image: reallity]

What's wrong? Why doesn't the parent `DIV` stretch to be able to contain whatever's inside?

[(not) Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/Z63gs/)
Rest of the CSS:

```
#menu {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  background-color: #CEE2FF;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #1868FF;
}
```

Comment: Try putting the <a> inside the <div>

Comment: @David The anchor is within the `div`, isn't it?

Comment: It can't be more in `div` than it already is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following css:

```
#menu div.item a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Before this code, the `a` tags are not being displayed as blocks and the container doesn't want to be friends with them.

Comment: @TomášZato - `display:inline-block` elements are inline-level elements that are block containers. That is their whole purpose. But you can even validly make elements `display:block` inside inline elements. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another/758491#758491) describes the CSS definitions that allow for that.

Answer (score 2):

The padding `5px` you used on the `a` tag will be partially applied but only `left-right` in respect to other sibling `inline` elements.

You're trying to set `padding` to `inline` elements, which is visually [not the desired](http://jsbin.com/AxuDOCO/1/edit). The **padding** on **inline** elements will refer to the textual *line*, but not in respect to the containing `block`[-level parent](http://jsbin.com/AxuDOCO/2/edit).
Remember that `padding` can be set to `block`-level elements such as 
 `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<p>` etc...

[**One fix**](http://jsbin.com/AxuDOCO/3/edit) is to use some [simple math and set **`line-height`**](http://jsbin.com/AxuDOCO/3/edit) to your `a`
[**The other**](http://jsbin.com/AxuDOCO/4/edit) is to set your `inline` anchors as **`display-block`** elements,
doing that way your elements will act contextually as `inline` elements while being allowed to take `block`-level elements properties.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/propidx.html

Also setting *just like that* an `inline` **any** element to be `inline-block` is **not the best choice** and is not fully compatible with **older browsers**.
`display-inline` for `span, a, b, i, s, q, u` **will work in all browsers**,
but generally speaking `span` is the perfect one to be used in that case cause even if an inline element by properties is similar to `div`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements

Comment: There's nothing wrong with setting vertical padding on inline elements, it just doesn't affect the height of the line box.

Answer (score 1):

From CSS 2.1 section [10.6.1 Inline, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced)

> The vertical padding, border and margin of an inline, non-replaced box
>   start at the top and bottom of the content area, and has nothing to do
>   with the 'line-height'. But only the 'line-height' is used when
>   calculating the height of the line box.

The height of the block div is the height of the stack of line boxes, which in this case is the height of the one and only line box. Which means that if you want to contain the `<a>` with padding, you need to set the line-height of the `<a>` element.

Add to your CSS

```
#menu div.item a{
  line-height:30px;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Z63gs/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting `overflow:hidden;` on your `#menu` item. http://jsfiddle.net/Z63gs/1/

This will just hide the extra fluff.  I think your padding is making the `<a>` elements larger than you would like.

Elliot's answer is much cleaner than this.