# how we can use canvas tag with hyper link tag

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

```
// This is the code in html part

<canvas id="canvas" width="684" height="606" style="background-color:#999999">

</canvas>
<a href="links/animation.html"><div style="width: 630px;height: 130px;" id="animation"></div></a>
<a href="pa1.html"><div style="width: 630px;height: 190px;" id="PA"></div></a>
<a href="web.html"><div style="width: 630px;height: 135px;" id="web"></div></a>

//This is the code in css part
#PA{
  position:relative;
  top:-545px;
  left:480px;
}
#web{
  position:relative;
  top:-510px;
  left:460px;
}
#animation{
  position:relative;
  top:-590px;
  left:460px;
}
```

This code created hyper link in canvas..But it is taking space after the canvas tag. I tried all the examples. But its not working. What is the problem in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute;`, which makes the the `<a>`s position relative to the `document`, like this:

```
a:nth-of-type(1){
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50px;
  background:red;
}

a:nth-of-type(2){
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px; 
  background:pink;
}

a:nth-of-type(3){
  position:absolute;
  top:150px;
  left:150px; 
  background:purple;
}

canvas{
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

P.S. I removed the `div`s from inside of the `a`s, because `div`s (block-level element) are not at all meant to be inside of an inline element. Instead, put `a` elements inside of `div`s if necessary.  ([Further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another))

Comment: In a canvas i have created 3 boxes.I have given 3 links to that boxes. It is my problem

Comment: I have another 3 links before these tags. If i applied u r code it will also apply to other links. I m not getting..

Comment: @user3232585 You want those 3 boxes to be inside the `canvas` ?