# What STYLES are allowed inside SPAN?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The "Style" of a SPAN applies until /SPAN.

But this does not apply to some attributes (e.g., background-color).

**Which attributes don't work?**

- Is the quality I am looking for called "deprecate"?
- Is it just background-color?
- Is there a substitute for "background-color" that does work?

**Thank you!**

PS - I found a complete (?) [Index of Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/index/attributes.html) (it does not have "background-color" - although it has "bgcolor" (which "deprecates")).

```html
<p>GDH2 no style</p>
<p  style="background-color:red; color:white; 
           font-size:140%; font-family:verdana; 
           text-align:center">
           GDH2 p style = bg color, font color, verdana, centered</p>

</span>
<span style="color:red; ">
    <p>GDH2 - inside span font color red = WORKS</p>
</span>
<span style="font-size:140%; ">
    <p>GDH2 - inside span font size 140% = WORKS</p>
</span>
<span style="font-family:verdana; ">
    <p>GDH2 - inside span Verdana = WORKS</p>
</span>
<span style="text-align:center; ">
    <p>GDH2 - inside span Verdana = WORKS</p>
</span>
<span style="background-color:blue; ">
    <p>GDH2 - inside span of bg color blue = <b>FAIL</b></p>
```

`

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another

Answer (score 1):

You can apply background-color to span

```
 <span  style="background-color:red; color:white; 
           font-size:140%; font-family:verdana; 
           text-align:center">
           GDH2 p style = bg color, font color, verdana, centered</span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/trzk4xm2/

Comment: This is not what op is asking. The problem is related to a block element put inside an inline element. In your example it only contains text.

Answer (score 1):

The html `p` (paragraph) won't inherit the `background-color` property from an `inline` parent (which is, btw wrong html in many lvls). Make that parent span NOT `inline` and you may have your color in the span... (Not in the paragraph)

Comment: That is correct, if you put plain text inside the span you will see the blue background color