# UL under LI inspite of block under Inline

Tags: html, css, html-lists, block, inline

I have the idea that placing a block under the inline is incorrect. However while building a tree structure we use `ul` under `li`. Could anyone please explain why this is a valid html?

Comment: `li` elements are `block` by default.  Even if you change them to `inline` using CSS, it's valid HTML to add block elements as their children.

Answer (score 0):

The default `display` value for the `li` property is not `inline`, it's `list-item`. And a `ul` is designed to be nested in a list, so there's no problem with placing a `ul` within an `li`.

Furthermore, as of HTML5, placing block elements inside inline elements is valid HTML.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline):*

> The distinction of block-level vs. inline elements is used in HTML
>   specifications up  to 4.01. In HTML5, this binary distinction is
>   replaced with a more complex set of content categories. The
>   "block-level" category roughly corresponds to the category of flow
>   content in HTML5, while "inline" corresponds to phrasing content, but
>   there are additional categories.

If, however, you don't want to put a block element within an inline element for [rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/746559/3597276) or other reasons, you have the option to change the `display` value:

```
<span style="display: block">
    <div style="display: inline"> ... </div>
</span>
```