# Margin does not collapse when block formatting context turned into block

Tags: html, css, margin

As I understand, a button element's `display` is `inline-block` which means it forms a BFC(block formatting context) and what I know abt BFC is that margins do not collapse between block elements outside of a BFC and that inside of BFC.

However, if a BFC's display type is set to 'block`, then margins should collapses as essentially we have turned`inline-block`into a regular`block` but that does not appear to happen in the following code.

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/fzf1fso5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="no-collapse">
  <h2> MARGIN <u>DO NOT</u> COLLAPSE</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam perspiciatis libero hic perferendis pariatur minus, officia fugiat id doloremque cum. Esse id, molestiae. Nihil similique libero deserunt, facilis fuga totam.</p>
  <button>
    <h2>BUTTON TURNED INTO BLOCK</h2> This is a button turned into regular block
    </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse">
  <h2> MARGIN COLLAPSES</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Magnam perspiciatis libero hic perferendis pariatur minus, officia fugiat id doloremque cum. Esse id, molestiae. Nihil similique libero deserunt, facilis fuga totam.</p>
  <p>Reguarl paragraph block</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.no-collapse {
  background-color: antiquewhite; 
  border: 1px dotted black}

div.collapse { background-color: aqua;}
button {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p { background-color: #ccc; }
```

Can anybody explain the reason why margins do not collapse for a BFC turned into block element ?

Comment: You can't put block level elements in a `button`....its invalid HTML. That's why.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another

Comment: the `display` has been set to `block` so technically it's no more different  than another block level element differing only by visual properties such as `background-color` and some others. Dimensional properties such as `width`, `height` `margin`, `padding` etc would be calculated as per block level elements algorithm.

Comment: Nope..check the link....it's more complicated than that. Regardless, it's invalid HTML

Answer (score 0):

[CSS 2.2 section 3.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/conform.html#conformance) says:

> CSS 2.2 does not define which properties apply to form controls and
>   frames, or how CSS can be used to style them. User agents may apply
>   CSS properties to these elements

This applies to buttons, and essentially means that all bets are off. So applying `display:block` to a button element, although it has some effects, does not simply make the button render as a block box in the way that, say, setting `display:block` on a span element does. In particular, it certainly does not change the way its content is rendered, and does does not stop the button from being a BFC to its content.

Comment: Possible correct way to interpret the behavior but still looking for a more concrete interpretation.