# How to solve Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: php, laravel

i am using laravel 5.5 when i want to hit the route it shows the following error like (Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found) but i completely fail to understand it it google it several time but not work any body help to solve this thanks in advance.

this is my route

```
Route::get('order/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@order');
Route::get('booking/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@booking');
```

this is my controller

```
public function index(){
        $categorys = DB::table('categories')->where('cate_status', '=', 'enable')->get();
        $rooms = DB::table('rooms')->where('status', '=', 'Enable')->get();
        return view('welcome', compact('categorys','rooms'));
    }


public function order($id){
            echo $id;
        }

    public function booking($id){
        echo $id;
    }
```

this is my views

```
@foreach($categorys as $category)
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <a href="{{url('order/'.$category->id)}}">
                            <img src="{{asset('assets/site')}}/images/menu/thumb/{{$category->cate_img}}" alt="chinese" class="img-responsive animation">
                            <div class="overlay animation">
                                <h4 class="text-uppercase">{{$category->cate_name}}</h4>
                            </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: from where are you getting `$categorys` in your view as you are not passing them?

Comment: from my index method and i want to call order route from my views

Comment: In which route you are getting this error

Comment: both routes booking and order

Comment: you should create a view for the methods and pass them with data `return view('users.index', compact('data'))`.

Comment: in my controller already to pass the data to view this the function public function index(){
     $categorys = DB::table('categories')->where('cate_status', '=', 'enable')->get();
     $rooms = DB::table('rooms')->where('status', '=', 'Enable')->get();
     return view('welcome', compact('categorys','rooms'));
    }

Comment: create for your `order` and `booking` methods. They are not related to index.

Comment: order and booking is already there i just pass the data to order method

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dollar sign from your routes and it should work.

```
Route::get('order/{id}', 'front\FrontController@order');
Route::get('booking/{id}', 'front\FrontController@booking');
```

You should also name your routes for easier maintenance and changes in the future.

```
Route::name('foobar')->get('url/{slug}/{date}', 'foo@BarController@foobar');
```

Usage:

```
route('foobar', ['slug' => 'stackoverflow', 'date' => '2018'])
```

If you later change the route to `->get('url/{date}/{slug}')`, the same `route` call will work.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `route()` something like this
Change.

```
<a href="{{url('order/'.$category->id)}}">
```

With

```
<a href="{{ route('order.get',$category->id) }}">
```

And change

```
Route::get('order/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@order');
```

With

```
Route::get('order/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@order')->name('order.get');
```

Make sure given controller path should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Regard to your error message you are calling wrong url for calling route. Update your routes:

```
Route::name('order.show')->get('order/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@order');
Route::name('booking.show')->get('booking/{$id}', 'front\FrontController@booking');
```

Then on your blade try to use named route:

```
@foreach($categorys as $category)
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="hover-content">
            <a href="{{route('order.show', $category)}}">
                <img src="{{asset('assets/site')}}/images/menu/thumb/{{$category->cate_img}}" alt="chinese" class="img-responsive animation">
                <div class="overlay animation">
                    <h4 class="text-uppercase">{{$category->cate_name}}</h4>
                </div>
            </a>
         </div>
     </div>
     @endforeach
```

> Your html should be change, it's not good to use div in a.

Comment: Why would it be bad to load a div inside an `a`?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746531/is-it-wrong-to-change-a-block-element-to-inline-with-css-if-it-contains-another