# Why does inline wrap so weird? Explain css inline behaviour

Tags: html, css, inline

I just do not understand what is going on in the styling here.
Perhaps I don't understand the inline rules.
The background of the outer div is overlapping the inner input element??

```css
    .outer{
      display: inline;
      padding: 20px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    .inner {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
Inline so bork?
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <input type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what were you expecting?

Comment: never put block element inside inline element

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is this an explicit rule? Does it say that in the spec.? I was wondering about that.

Comment: I would say this is more a *logical* rule and yes the spec describe this, will try to gather the relevant information

Comment: OP & @TemaniAfif - Perhaps this'll help: [Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758491/2026606)

Comment: @TylerRoper exactly, I was also looking for that one ;)

Comment: if you still don't understand why the background is like that let me know (you have to also understand how padding behave on inline element)

Comment: @TylerRoper Thank you all for the resources, I suppose I have some reading to do later in my free time. =)