# Why are there extra 2px added to the line-height of a block container that contains inline-elements?

Tags: html, css

```css
.link {
  background-color: red;
  font-size:16px;
}

.link span {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
    <span>textg</span>
</div>
```

The line-height of the container should be size of the font-size, i.e. 16px, but instead it's 18.4px. If you reduce the font-size to 15px, the line-height becomes 17.4px. Where do these 2.4px come from?

Here's a snapshot just in case.

[image]

Comment: I think you are coming up against leading - to use an old metal printing term - a bit of space before and after a line of type. This recent article [link]https://css-tricks.com/how-to-tame-line-height-in-css/ may be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The line-height of the container should be size of the font-size, i.e. 16px

No it's not. You never set the `line-height` of the parent so [the default value](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) will apply which is around `1.2`. It can be different in some case but for sure bigger than `1` in all the cases so bigger than the defined `font-size`

Set an explicit `line-height` and you will get what you want:

```css
.link {
  background-color: red;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:1; /* or any pixel value */
}

.link span {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
    <span>textg</span>
</div>
```

No need to set the `line-height` of the inline element because it will inherit it from the parent.

Also setting the `line-height` to only the inline element will do nothing to its parent since you have two line-height. The one of the parent that define the minimum height of the line box and the one of the child that can **only increase** the line box height (beyond the minimum value) and never decrease it.

```css
.link {
  background-color: red;
  font-size:16px;
  line-height:16px;
  margin:10px;
}

.link span {
  background-color: royalblue;
  font-size:16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
    <span style="line-height:0;">I will do nothing !!</span>
</div>


<div class="link">
    <span style="line-height:40px;">I will make the parent bigger</span>
</div>
```

> On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies **the minimal height of line boxes** within the element.

> On a non-replaced inline element, 'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height)</sup>

Comment: So, "Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based on the font of the element".. this does not mean that the line-height of a block container is going to be same size as the font-size by default? The "1.2" in unitless number is relative to the font-size, correct? So, i guess that's where the discrepancy comes from.

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks yes, line-height need to be bigger than 1 (1xfont-size) to avoid having a collapse effect between lines. A smal line-height will make the different line very close so we use a *reasonable* value that will give us a good amount of space between text in different lines

Comment: Okay, thanks. If i may ask one more question, a bit unrelated, but - when you want to remove the descender line space by making the img, inside a link element, a block, is that not actually an invalid code? Since technically line boxes cannot contain block-level boxes. So, while it fixes that particular issue, i am wondering if that is not actually invalid?

Comment: @Ihatecontrolfreaks it's valid and there are rules for such case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/758491/8620333