# Inline SVG increases height of parent element - why and how to prevent it?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts

I'm including an `svg` element in a `h1` like this:

```
<h1>
    64px ABC
    <span class="icon">
        <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
            <rect id="block" x="4" y="4" width="56" height="56" rx="16" ry="16" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg> 
    </span>
    xyz
</h1>
```

I then position the icon a little lower to align nicely with the text using relative positioning.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.14453125em; /* Calculated using https://seek-oss.github.io/capsize/ */
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  fill: currentColor;
}
```

This all works, but at a height of 1em, the `svg` increases the `height` of it's parent element.

This is the `h1` without the `svg`:

[image]

And this is with the `svg` included:

[image]

There's a difference of 5px.

When I change the height to e.g. .9em, this doesn't happen.

I've tried many different options, without the desired result - being to keep the height of the parent element unchanged.

*Why does this happen and how can we make sure it doesn't?*

CodePen: https://codepen.io/denobelsoftware/pen/MWjKKXO

```js
let iconsHidden = false;
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".icon");

document.querySelector("#hide-icons").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(iconsHidden){
      elements[i].classList.add('hidden');
    } else elements[i].classList.remove('hidden');
}
  iconsHidden = !iconsHidden;
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative; /* for the rulers */
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.14453125em;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

h1:after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.244140625em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);
    z-index: -100;
}

h1:before{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.955078125em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);
    z-index: -100;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        64px ABC
        <span class="icon">
            <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect id="block" x="4" y="4" width="56" height="56" rx="16" ry="16" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg> 
        </span>
        xyz
    </h1>

    <h1>
        64px ABC
        <span class="icon">
            <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect id="block" x="4" y="4" width="56" height="56" rx="16" ry="16" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg>
        </span>
        xyz
    </h1>

    <input type="checkbox" id="hide-icons">
    <label for="hide-icons"> Hide icons</label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the span `display:inline-block` and add `vertical-align:top` to avoid the default baseline alignment that will make the linebox bigger then also use `line-height:0` to make sure the svg inside will not affect its size. Then you may need to readjust the top value:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700&display=swap');

h1 {
    font-size: 64px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: relative; /* for the rulers */
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  top: 0.14453125em;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  line-height:0;
}

svg {
  height: 1em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

h1:after{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.244140625em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);
    z-index: -100;
}

h1:before{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0.955078125em;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.23);
    z-index: -100;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>
        64px ABC
        <span class="icon">
            <svg width="64" height="64" viewBox="0 0 64 64" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <rect id="block" x="4" y="4" width="56" height="56" rx="16" ry="16" stroke-width="1" />
            </svg> 
        </span>
        xyz
    </h1>

    <h1>
        64px ABC

        xyz
    </h1>

    <input type="checkbox" id="hide-icons">
    <label for="hide-icons"> Hide icons</label>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this avoids the bigger linebox. It also makes the text in the h1 vertical-align to the top, which should stay baseline. Do you see a way to avoid this?

Comment: @RNobel how it's making the h1 aligned to top? as you can see both examples are exactly the same (with and without the icon)

Comment: When you open dev tools and disable ```vertical-align: top;``` you'll see that the text moves down

Comment: @RNobel and this is exactly your issue. The text moves down because the span is creating more space on the bottom thus it needs more space on the top to be placed inside the line. That space is the culprit making your linebox bigger. The text is not moving and the baseline is not changing, the span is making the difference

Comment: @RNobel notice how your pseudo element aren't moving but since the line is bigger then logically it will need more vertical space and you have the illusion of the text being pushed down but it's not. It's the linebox that was bigger like you noticed and you wanted to fix

Comment: Ah, now I get it! :) So if I measure the distance between the baseline and top it's 59px. The span is 64px high, so there's 5px short. This causes the box to grow with 5px and the text looks like it's pushed down 5px because of that. Setting ```vertical-align: top;``` changes this because between top and bottom, there's more than enough space to fit the 64px. Is that correct?

Comment: @RNobel yes, the span was initially aligned to the baseline so as you said it start from there and grow to the top with its height. I changed this so it start from the top to the bottom instead and only its 64px will be considered which is OK since the linebox height is already bigger than that so it fits inside (the line-height:0 wll also ensure we don't have more than 64px inside the span too)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Are there any resources or courses that cover details like this?

Comment: @RNobel I wrote some answers around that topic if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978512/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/64959101/8620333 /  https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319772/8620333

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me hours of trials, after having already spent hours of trials ...