# How to set style on an element after setting `all: initial;` on it?

Tags: html, css

I have a box, to prevent it and its children from inheriting properties from outside world, I set  `all: initial;` on the box. But with this setting, I can't set other styles on it anymore.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer {
  color: red;
}
.inner {
  all: initial;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>yes</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example above, what I expect is the background is blue but font color is black(initial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because `all:initial` will also set `display` to `initial` which is `inline` so you will end having a block element (`p`) inside an inline one (`div`). You need to add `display:block`

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer {
  color: red;
}
.inner {
  all: initial;
  display:block;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>yes</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The coloration was working fine but the output is not the intented one. Some padding will show this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.outer {
  color: red;
}
.inner {
  all: initial;
  padding:5px;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <p>yes</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Related: [Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/746531/8620333)