# CSS - universal selector and "unwrapped" content

Tags: css

I am trying to style all div's content, using the universal selector (*)
The issue is - if the content is not `<span>`, `<p>`, `<hX>` etc - it is not being selected. any suggestions how to solve this )if possible at all)?

CSS:

```
#content * {          
    background-color: green;
    padding:10px;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content">

  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <p>test paragraph</p>

  and this fails to be selected

</div>
```

I have reasons not to wrap that line.

Here's JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yroLx1kj/

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `#content *,#content {}`

Comment: This won't do exactly what is needed:
https://jsfiddle.net/yroLx1kj/1/
But thanks

Comment: @0stone0 , partially. I am not selecting that particular bit of text without tags. I'd like to apply the same style for all elements(which, logically, is relied to your suggestion but not entirely what I am looking for) (I guess ) 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A hacky idea (I said hacky ...) is to rely on `display:inline` that will break the layout and you will get the output you want.

```css
#content *,
#content {
  background-color: green;
  color: #FFF;
}

#content * {
  padding: 10px;
}

#content {
  display: inline; /* this will do the magic */
  padding: 10px 0;
}

/* the below to add the right padding, still don't know for the left one */
#content::after {
  content: "    ";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">

  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <p>test paragraph</p>

  and this fails to be selected

</div>
```

Read the following to understand how this hack works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/758491/8620333

Comment: Haaa ))) twisted logic, indeed. Thanks Afif )))
I won't use this but  - it , indeed, does what I asked ))