# Why does display: inline-block need to be set on <a> for its pseudoelement to be same width as it?

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/eNNdme), which shows how to animate a bottom "border" that's actually a pseudoelement. Here's the code:

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The part I don't understand is that without setting `display: inline-block` on the `a` (the default is `inline`), on hover the pseudoelement spans the full width of the `li`, whereas with `display: inline-block`, the pseudoelement is the same width as the `a` element only. What explains the difference in behavior?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/758491/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS widths, [when specified as a percentage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width):

> Defines the width as a percentage of ***the containing block's width***.

If the `a` is *inline* it is not the containing *block*, the `li` is.