# Turning the background color red using the :host selector?

Tags: css, angular, sass

In this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdbamb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html) the background turns red with this selector:

```
  styles: [
    `
    :host .background-div {
      background-color: red;
    }
  `,
  ]
```

However if we remove the `.background-div` part of the selector and only use the `:host` selector like this:

```
    :host {
      background-color: red;
    }
```

The background of the element is not turned red.  Just curious why?

Comment: why are you surprised? if your remove background-div it's another selector selecting another element

Comment: I was thinking that `:host` is synonymous with the `button-overview-example` component element ... so using the `:host:` selector as expressed would turn the background red ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand your argument, why isn't red color being applied to the host component? The OP meant the background of the element being created by Angular, `<button-overview-example>`

Comment: @JuanMendes I am not seeing any element here. I see two different selector selecting two different element so I won't be surprised if the result is not the same. We need to see a working code to know why the last one is not doing anything

Comment: If you examine the HTML, you'll see an attribute applied to the host, `_nghost-amx-c311` and the corresponding style `[_nghost-amx-c311] {
    background-color: red;
}` The whole node should have a red background but there's something interfering.

Comment: @JuanMendes I don't open external links, the OP is required to add all the relevant code inside the question.

Comment: I'm letting you know that I did open the link, and that your comment doesn't really apply, then  The OP posted a link to working code, which cannot be reproduced inside StackOverflow. And I thought I was a stickler.

Comment: *which cannot be reproduced inside StackOverflow* --> then the question is off-topic because that link will one day die or get updated with something else

Comment: Indeed ... We can't post running SASS webcontainer code inside SO ... All Angular MVCE must run in a web container or stackblitz browser environment ...

Comment: Also, as noted here https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/ , the semantics for `host` in Angular are a little different because of the way Angular goes about style encapsulation ...

Comment: @TemaniAfif I put an update comment in the question crediting your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Temani Afif` pointed out in the comment, the `:host` element is not rendering the red background because the display property for it is set to `inline`.

If we change the `display` property to something other than `inline`, like `block`, the background will be rendered `red` as expected.

Here is a demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdbamb-9p84h4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.ts

Comment: I think your answer is not very accurate. The issue is that the custom element is by default an inline element that contain a block element. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72454494/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right, thank you. I adjusted the answer, but I still can't tell where the component is set to `inline` though. Feel free to add to or correct the answer further.

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif ! This question was bothering me, especially all the wrong answers that others were suggesting that misunderstood `:host` (including all the stuff previously in this question). I did miss the fact that the element was inline. It would be good to point out that `:host` has nothing to do with the problem. You should never have a block element inside an inline element. I am guessing you gave in, realized this was a valid question and did look into the link, eh? 