# A tag with Div tag

Tags: html, css

This is my code

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
        Visit W3Schools.com!
    </div>
</a>
```

My div width is 200PX. But my link is activated right side of the white space. How to activate link only within the div width, ie within 200px?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/8620333

Comment: if you want to have accurate detail about what is happening and why it covers the whole width, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/758491/8620333 and here is a demo to show you that it's more complex than what you might think: https://jsfiddle.net/L8u3eghf/

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to do:

```html
<a style="display:inline-block;" href="https://www.w3schools.com"><div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black;">Visit W3Schools.com!</div></a>
```

Or

```html
<a style="display:block; width:fit-content;" href="https://www.w3schools.com"><div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black;">Visit W3Schools.com!</div></a>
```

Comment: Yes it is working now. My question is: Why to add inline-block?

Comment: `<a>` is normally `display: inline` and `<div>` is normally `display: block`. You're not supposed to put block-level elements inside of inline elements. It seems there's a quirk in this case where doing so causes the `<a>` to extend as far as it can when there's a `<div>` inside of it. Normally this would be expected since block-level elements are normally full width. You've set a width on the `<div>` so the `<a>` should shrink to match. But it doesn't. The CSS I added makes the desired behavior explicit.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of nesting the div in the a- element, make it its parent.

```html
<div> <div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
</div>
```

Have fun coding!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```html
<div style="width:200px; border:1px solid black;">
    <a style="display:flex; width: 100%;" href="https://www.w3schools.com">
        Visit W3Schools.com!
    </a>
</div>
```