# why does display:inline in ul css tag causes elements to shift

Tags: html, css

please see html [image: invalid html]validator error output in screenshot.

```css
ul{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>hi
    <li>
        1234
    </li>
    <li>
       5678
    </li>
 </ul>   
     
<ul>hello
    <li>
       abcdef
    </li>
    <li>
       ghijkl
    </li>
 </ul>
```

question:the ul items(hi,hello) in above css code moved a couple of places to the right if I used the css display:inline tag . But They do not get moved if I execute with a css ul tag having no display:inline value..please explain. and second question why have the circle markers disappeared ?

Comment: You transformed your code into something wrong because you have list-item elements inside inline element.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid to start with:  https://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`li` elements have a display value equal to `list-item` and following [the specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-display/#the-display-properties) they generate a block box so you end having **a block element inside and inline element**.

The above behavior is also defined in the specification and leads to the result you get. More detail: [Is it wrong to change a block element to inline with CSS if it contains another block element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/746531/8620333)

> why have the circle markers disappeared ?

It's still there but hidden on the left because the default behavior is `list-style-position: outside`

```css
ul{
    display: inline;
}
li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>hi
    <li>
        1234
    </li>
    <li>
       5678
    </li>
 </ul>   
     
<ul>hello
    <li>
       abcdef
    </li>
    <li>
       ghijkl
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ul` gets a default `padding-left` applied from the user agent stylesheet, `40px` or something.

With an `inline` element, `padding-left` works only before the first *line* of content, and `padding-right` only after the *last* line.

Make it `inline-block` instead, if you want that padding applied to the whole element.

Answer (score 0):

Because the **inline** value of the **display** property is something that makes the elements inside to behaves inline.

That means you have not much options to position and move them.

The **inline** value is most useful for a text paragraphs to wrap theentire paragraph. Where you would like the text to position in a couple of lines one below another.