# Can an anonymous block box create an inline formatting context like that created by a block container box when it has no block-level elements?

Tags: html, css, w3c

According to the documentation, it states the following:

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level

> The line boxes before the break and after the break are enclosed in
> anonymous block boxes, and the block-level box becomes a sibling of
> those anonymous boxes.

Question 1: Does this mean that the inline-level elements are **contained within an anonymous block box**?

Question 2: If so, does this mean that within each anonymous block box an inline formatting context is **created as the one created by a block container box that contains no block-level boxes**?

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#inline-formatting

> An inline formatting context is established by a block container box
> that contains no block-level boxes. In an inline formatting context,
> boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the
> top of a containing block.

Comment: yes and yes, the reason anonymous box exist is to avoid having inline and block element inside the same formatting context so we create an anonymous one for the inline formatting context and the latter will be part of the block formatting context

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif +1, I thought the formatting context that created an anonymous block box for this case was something different than a "traditional" inline formatting context. Happy to get an answer from a CSS reference like you :)

Comment: One last question @Temani Afif, that means that these anonymous block boxes are block-level boxes, right?

Comment: @Coder23 - All block boxes, anonymous or otherwise, are block-level boxes.

Comment: hi @Alohci +1, great, thank you very much for confirming